# Searchable dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary

I used the code from searchable dictionary to make my own dictionary. Now i would like to know, how i can edit the database in order to insert and display my own words and definitions?

Comment: Please show us some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to edit the "definition.txt" that is in res/raw with your own words.

edit: for those who wish, the code is publicly available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm)